# how to write custom command test statement that takes in an argument and then does file editing?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have a custom command in my Django 1.10 called `upload_pics_for_variants.py`

What it does is it takes in an argument about a directory path and then proceeds to use my app models to upload jpg images.

Hence my command is

`python manage.py upload_pics_for_variants tmp/some_folder` and it works perfectly

I have read about [how to write unit tests for custom command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#management-commands) but it looks like it will simply test a command that has no arguments and then expects a certain output.

How should I write my unit test to properly test my custom command class that is supposed to behave as stated above?

Answer (score 0):

[`call_command()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#django.core.management.call_command) takes arguments, so you could set up a directory with some test images and pass its path as an argument to `call_command()` from your test method. Then you could check that the correct database objects were created.

Alternatively, if you have some complex logic to test, you could mock out the code that finds the images and the code that writes to the database, then just test the logic.